# Erro de Proxy no Google Trends

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou usando o Google Trends no ASP.NET MVC 5.

Sempre que vou executar minha aplicação no Visual Studio o Google Trends automaticamente bloqueia meu proxy.

O que pode estar causando isso?

Answer (score 0):

por padrão, o Google Trends  bloqueia todos os proxy de acesso, já tive este problema,
 use o [https-proxy-agent].

Eu resolvi criando um banco de dados e nele alimentar milhares de Ips, que vinha de um gerador de proxy e minha aplicação consumia estes proxy, só assim consegui resolver este problema ate hoje esta rodando.